# POST document with Django RequestFactory instead of form data

Tags: python, django, testing

I'd like to build a request for testing middleware, but I don't want POST requests to always assume I'm sending form data. Is there a way to set `request.body` on a request generated from `django.test.RequestFactory`?

I.e., I'd like to do something like:

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
import json

factory = RequestFactory(content_type='application/json')
data = {'message':'A test message'}
body = json.dumps(data)
request = factory.post('/a/test/path/', body)

# And have request.body be the encoded version of `body`
```

The code above will fail the test because my middleware needs the data to be passed as the document in `request.body` not as form data in `request.POST`. However, `RequestFactory` always sends the data as form data.

I can do this with `django.test.Client`:

```
from django.test import Client
import json

client = Client()
data = {'message':'A test message'}
body = json.dumps(data)
response = client.post('/a/test/path/', body, content_type='application/json')
```

I'd like to do the same thing with `django.test.RequestFactory`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RequestFactory has built-in support for JSON payloads. You don't need to dump your data first. But you should be passing the content-type to `post`, not to the instantiation.

```
factory = RequestFactory()
data = {'message':'A test message'}
request = factory.post('/a/test/path/', data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Ahh - I see, defaults are not applied until after the request data is processed: https://github.com/django/django/blob/47bb3b68ff67a29da308b42e7950ca46df74b52b/django/test/client.py#L414  Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman `request.data` and `request.POST` are empty. Did i missed something?

Comment: Hmmm. When I removed content_type="application/json", request.POST had content.

Comment: Why doesn't `factory.post` actually post the data to the view, whereas `client.post` does?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried Jay's solution and didn't work, but after some reseach, this did (Django 2.1.2)

```
factory = RequestFactory()    
request = factory.post('/post/url/')
request.data = {'id': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

In later version of Django (tested on 4.0) this is no longer an issue. On the other hand, to pass data to `request.POST` might be.

In default, when passing `content-type` to a RequestFactory, data goes into `request.body` and when you don't, data goes into `request.POST`.

```py
request_factory = RequestFactory()

# provide content-type
request = request_factory.post(f'url', data={'foo': 'bar'}, content_type="application/json")
print(request.body)  # b'{"foo": "bar"}'

# don't provide content type
request = request_factory.post(f'url', data={'foo': 'bar'})
print(request.POST)  # <QueryDict: {'foo': ['bar']}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me in Django 4.1:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from customauth import views


class RegistrationViewTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
    
    def test_post_request_creates_new_user(self):
        data = {
            'email': 'new_user@email.com',
            'screen_name': 'new_user',
            'password1': 'new_user_password',
            'password2': 'new_user_password',
        }
        request = self.factory.post('/any/path/will/do/', data )
        middleware = SessionMiddleware(request)
        middleware.process_request(request)
        request.session.save()
        response = views.registration_view(request)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        # ok
```

This test passes. The form was successfully processed in `views.registration_view`.

Note:

- When I included `content_type='application/json'` in the call to `self.factory.post` (as the accepted answer suggests), `request.POST` had no content in the view. Without that, it worked. I don't know why but would be happy to learn.
- I needed to manually added `SessionMiddleware` to `request`.