# APIView chaining in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to chain the call of API's, what I have is:

```
from django.views import View
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ChildAPI(APIView)
  def get(self, request):
    store_id = request.GET.get('store_id')

    prodcuts = ProductsModel.objects\
               .filter(store_id=store_id)\
               .annotate(SUM('price'))... etc
    x = products['price__sum']
    y = products['tax__sum']
```

Now rather then returning an response from the `ChildAPI` I rather would like to pass the `x` and `y` parameters via `post` to `ParentAPI` which will then return the response as:

```
class ParentAPI(APIView):
  def post(self, request):
    store_id = request.POST.get('store_id')
    x = request.POST.get('x')
    y = request.POST.get('y')
    AwesomeModel.objects.filter(...).update(x=x,y=y)
    return Response({"code": 1, "message": "Updated"})
```

I was reading [Calling a REST API from Django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663945/calling-a-rest-api-from-django-view),
As the parameters aren't passed via `post` and `url` is hited via `requests`, can't I do it without `domainname.com` i.e. as we do via `namespace` from Django `templates` as:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'product:update-product' %}">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ x }}" name="x">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ y }}" name="y">
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

**Note:** I have the `ParentAPI url` pattern in another Django App `urls` file, 

**The way we call one function from another can I call one API from another passing parameters wrapped via `post`**

## UPDATED:

Here the `ParentAPI` is called independently as well, so I want to pass parameters wrapped into `request` via `post` only. Can't pass them to function as `ParentAPI.post(request, x=x)`

If `ParentAPI` was hit independently, then rather I would have created a function with variable argument parameter `**kwarg` and called the function.
If I do so I will have:

```
class ParentAPI(APIView):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    x = request.POST.get('x')
    if not x:
      x = kwargs['x']
```

Basically I want to send `x,y` wrapped into `request`. So as it can be accessed by `ParentAPI` as `request.POST.get('x')` or `reques.POST['x']`

Comment: maybe `requests.post()` will work but will take `domainname.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this,

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class Parent(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data={"store_id": kwargs['store_id']})


class ChildAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        store_id = request.GET.get('store_id')
        parent = Parent()
        return parent.post(request, store_id=store_id)
```

Access the child api , `/child/?store_id=12323` and you will get response from `Parent` API

Comment: won't this change the way `ParentAPI` accept the parameters? Now It is taking them via `kwargs['x']`, whereas earlier it was getting them as `request.POST.get('x')`

Comment: You can't alter the `request.POST` attribute, because `request` object is ***immutable***

Comment: You can't ***mimic*** the `HTTP POST` request *directly*. What you can try is , mock the request object.. [see the realted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306177/post-document-with-django-requestfactory-instead-of-form-data)